# How do i find the knot vector of a shape on a cartesian plane?

Tags: python, math, spline

I have a concave polygon, with the following points on a 2D plane. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8eVI.jpg)

How do i find the knot vector using uniform spacing. So i can convert this shape into a spline, preferably b-spline.

I understand how it works with a regular number line but I am very confused if its the same for 2D.

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you are using and include what source code you have so far. If this question is purely about mathematics and not computer programming, you should be asking it on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as Wikipedia says: Non-uniform rational basis spline (NURBS) is a mathematical model using basis splines (B-splines) that is commonly used in computer graphics for representing curves and surfaces.  Isnt your image already converted in this format?